I'm looking for a statistics book
I remember that it was about statistics and probability, it was over 300 pages long and George Pólya was one of the authors (there were several). Does anyone know what the name of that book is? I haven't been able to find it on the internet.

https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262160971/george-polya-collected-papers/

thanks you, !!!!
